# How to deploy MongoDB as a single replica in a docker locally?

Tags: mongodb, docker

I am trying to run the latest version of MongoDB as Single Replica Set in a docker locally.

docker-compose.yml

```
version: "3.9"
services:
  mongodb:
    build:
      context: ./mongo/
    restart: always
    hostname: mongodb
    environment:
      - PUID=1000
      - PGID=1000
      - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME=mongo
      - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD=mongo
      - MONGO_REPLICA_SET_NAME=rs0
    volumes:
      - mongodb_data:/data/db
    ports:
      - 27017:27017
    healthcheck:
      test: |
        test $$(mongosh --quiet -u mongo -p mongo --eval "rs.initiate({ _id: 'rs0', members: [{ _id: 0, host: 'mongodb:27017' }] })") \
          && test $$(mongosh --quiet -u mongo -p mongo --eval "
      interval: 10s
      start_period: 30s
    networks:
      - default

  mongodb-express:
    image: mongo-express
    restart: always
    depends_on:
      - mongodb
    ports:
      - 8081:8081
    environment:
      ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_ADMINUSERNAME: mongo
      ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_ADMINPASSWORD: mongo
      ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_URL: mongodb://mongo:mongo@mongodb:27017/?authSource=admin&readPreference=primary&ssl=false&replicaSet=rs0
    networks:
      - default

volumes:
  mongodb_data:

networks:
  default:
    driver: bridge
```

Content of Dockerfile in ./mongo

```
FROM mongo
RUN echo "password" > /keyfile \
  && chmod 600 /keyfile \
  && chown 999 /keyfile \
  && chgrp 999 /keyfile
CMD ["--bind_ip_all", "--keyFile", "/keyfile", "--replSet", "rs0"]
```

After launching containers, I see errors in the container logs

```
"ctx":"monitoring-keys-for-HMAC","msg":"Failed to refresh key cache","attr":{"error":"NotYetInitialized: Cannot use non-local read concern until replica set is finished initializing.","nextWakeupMillis":24000}}
```

Also, when I try to connect via pymongo

```
from pymongo.mongo_client import MongoClient

client = MongoClient("mongodb://mongo:mongo@mongodb:27017/?authSource=admin&readPreference=primary&ssl=false&replicaSet=rs0")

db = client["examplebase"]
```

I get the following error

```
pymongo.errors.ServerSelectionTimeoutError: No replica set members match selector "<function readable_server_selector at 0x000001AA210E4FE0>", Timeout: 30s, Topology Description: <TopologyDescription id: 6453c0ed1bf3534486f16349, topology_type: ReplicaSetNoPrimary, servers: [<ServerDescription ('mongodb', 27017) server_type: RSGhost, rtt: 0.0>]>
```

I hope for your help in my attempts to understand the root of the problem and how to solve it. As I have already googled a lot